# Replace elements in a matrix (Need help to make this faster)

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, multiprocessing, mpi

## C is composed of elements of the array B and i want to change each element which would correspond to A

```
#Program Block starts

import numpy as np
A= np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
B= np.array([1, 5, 3, 9, 15] )

# I have a 3*3 matrix

C = [[0 for x in range(3)] for x in range(3)]
C[0][:]=[1,5,3]
C[1][:]=[7,9,15]
C[2][:]=[2,9,15]


flag=(A==B).astype(int) # comparing for equality of 2 arrays A and B, and storing as binary

C_new=np.copy(C)

flag_ind=[i for i, e in enumerate(flag) if e==0] # storing the indices of non differing elements

for x in flag_ind: 
    C_new[C_new==B[x]]=A[x]
```

The output will be C_new=[1, 2, 3; 7 4 5; 2 4 5]
The actual sizes of A and B are ~ 600000 , size of C is 4000000*4.. time for simulation is taking ~ 14 hrs.. If there is a way to do the same operation with greater speed ..kindly let me know

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This way you are iterating over the entire C array as many times as the intersection between A and B.

What I suggest is creating a dictionary that maps the B values to the A values so that you can retrieve every equivalent element in approximately constant time.

This is what I did, it took 9s to run with arrays of the same size as you specified.

```
A_dict = dict((k, v) for k, v in zip(B, A) if k != v)
map_c = np.vectorize(lambda x: A_dict.get(x, x))
C_new = map_c(C)
```

First I created the dictionary to map every value from B that has a different equivalent on A, then I created the function that will use this dictionary on the C array.

Comment: Thanks a lot.. I shall try to run this and compare the times.. Appreciate it !

Comment: I made a little improvement, take a look.

Comment: I tested with random arrays of the same size as you said an it took 9s on my computer.

Comment: Oh! Great... I have started running my code .. I shall let you know soon.